# glew causes screen to flicker between red and black. glad works

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glfw, glew

I'm doing my programming on MacOS 10.14.3 that has support for OpenGL 4.1.

I'm using glfw for the ui and glew for the extensions detection.

this is the my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
const GLint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

int main() {

    if (!glfwInit()) {
        std::cout << "GLFW initialisation Failed";
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR,4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR,1);
    // Core profile = No Backwards Compatibility
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    // Allow forward compatibility
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT,GL_TRUE);

    GLFWwindow *mainWindow = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Test Window", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!mainWindow) {
        std::cout << "GLFW window creation Failed!";
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }
    // get buffer size information
    int bufferWidth, bufferHeight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(mainWindow,&bufferWidth,&bufferHeight);

    // Set context for GLEW to use
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(mainWindow);

    // Allow modern extension features
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cout << "GLEW initialisation Failed!";
        glfwDestroyWindow(mainWindow);
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup viewport size
    glViewport(0,0,bufferWidth,bufferHeight);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(mainWindow)) {
        // Get + handle user input events
        glfwPollEvents();
        // Clear window
        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glfwSwapBuffers(mainWindow);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this should be a basic started for an opengl application. it should init glfw and glew and paint the screen in red, and on top of that I can add my opengl drawing/rendering functions.

when I execute it instead of seeing a window with a red background color, the background color flickers between red and black.

any ideas why?

## update

it appears that the screen flickers between black and red even if I choose a different color with glClearColor.

starting to think maybe glew isn't working properly.. i'll move back to glad and seee if there is any difference.

## update 2

replaced glew with glad by removed glew code, generating glad code using the web interface, then included `glad.h` and added `glad.c` to compilation, and initialised glad with:

```
if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
```

ok now that works properly... but I want to use glew... what may be the problem that's causing this ?

Comment: What screenbuffer format do you have?  Is it single- or double-buffered?

Comment: @BenVoigt - this is the entire code.. guess i'm missing setting something to enable double buffering ? :) i'm really new to this so sorry if i'm not more helpful

Comment: the docs says that glfw uses double buffering my default

Comment: adding glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DOUBLEBUFFER,GL_TRUE); provides the same results

Comment: @genpfault - use CLion to build and run the app, created a CMakeLists.txt with libGL, libGLEW and libglfw dynamic libs

Comment: I don't think this causes your problem, but a comment on your code: You don't need to call `glClearColor` in every iteration of the loop. You only need to call it once and the color is stored in the OpenGL state.

Comment: @AlbertM - won't I still need to call glClearColor() to clear the screen after each frame? glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) is not enough as far as I understand

Comment: `glClearColor` needs to be called only once, it tells OpenGL which color to use for clearing the buffer. `glClear` has to be called every frame (unless you are sure that you overwrite every pixel anyways) and actually clears the buffer with the color that you have previously specified.

Comment: Besides this your code looks good to me and if I run it on my machine it displays a solid red window without flickering as expected. So this seems to be a problem of your system (maybe check if your graphics driver has an available update or any known issues that could be related to this).

Comment: @AlbertM - weird.. before that I did some opengl programming on that same machine with glut I think..  and i do play opengl games so.. i'll investigate this. thanks

Comment: Apple is removing OpenGL from macOS, and promoting Metal 2 as the alternative.  So depending on your project, you may want to consider your technology options.